# Bzr completely delete revisions (with files)

Tags: version-control, dvcs, bazaar, launchpad

I've unintentionally committed some confidential files to a bzr branch. What's even more sticky is that I also pushed them to launchpad.

I made a bzr revert but, if I go to that *dirty* revision, I can still see those files. Is it possible to completely return to a previous revision, so that those files completely disappear?

Or as an alternative, if I delete the `trunk` branch of a launchpad project, will I be able to create a new `trunk`?

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262203/delete-file-history-with-bazaar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So according to TridenT's and jelmer's recommendations the solution is:

```
1.) `bzr uncommit -r X` Where X is the revision I want to return to
2.) `bzr commit` This created the local revision X+1
3.) `bzr push --overwrite -r X+1` This pushed the stuff to launchpad,
```

and all those sticky files are gone.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

If you delete the trunk branch of a launchpad you will be able to create a new trunk.

You can also completely go back to the previous revision by using "bzr push --overwrite -rREVNO" where REVNO is the revision you want to go back to.

Comment: Thank you jelmer. However unfortunately this doesn't work. If I try `bzr push --overwrite -r X`, it says `No new revisions to push.` and no change happens.

Comment: Ok, in conjunction with TridenT's solution it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `uncommit`.
For the user, this will remove it from the branch.
In the bzr repo, it will in fact unlink the revision from the main line.